# CORS Fix for BabylonLoader.js in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, cors, image-loading

To amuse myself I have been working my way through the old NeHe demos and implementing them in three.js.  You can see the progress so far [here](http://geofx.com/graphics/nehe-three-js/nehe-three-js.html).  I have gotten to 31 which uses models.  I thought it would be fun to test out the various model loaders.  So far, I got OBJ and Collada to work but Babylon kept giving me cross-origin errors.  Basically the same error as seen in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853339/three-js-collada-textures-not-loading).  So I tried the same fix suggested by AJ Campbell in that post, i.e. I changed the BabylonLoader load method by adding the line *loader.crossOrigin = '';*  Thus:

```
load: function ( url, onLoad, onProgress, onError ) {

    var scope = this;

    var loader = new THREE.FileLoader( scope.manager );
    loader.crossOrigin = '';        // added by rkwright 
    loader.load( url, function ( text ) {

        onLoad( scope.parse( JSON.parse( text ) ) );

    }, onProgress, onError );

},
```

This works perfectly, but it may not be the right solution (seems hackish).  Seems like this is a bug (missing code) in three.js?

Comment: Using `loader.crossOrigin = '';` is usual practice for loaders against CORS in Three.js.

Comment: I'm OK with that.  But I had to add it to the BabylonLoader to get it to work.  Should I submit a PR to three.js?  All this is with the current master r84.

Comment: `var loader = new THREE.BabylonLoader(); loader.crossOrigin = ''; loader.load(...);` It's without adding any lines to the source code of the loader.

Comment: But the code " loader.crossOrigin = '': "  doesn't exist in the BabylonLoader.js. And I can't create a pull request for three.js because I don't have commit rights.

Comment: Yeah, you're right ) My mistake.

Comment: Now added the support for PDB with the same problem.  Solved the same way.  It appears that the model loader modules are not exactly up to date.  My code is [here](https://github.com/rkwright/nehe-three-js/tree/develop), BTW.